# Disable wrapping migration in a transaction with Node db-migrate

Tags: node.js, postgresql, transactions, database-migration, dbmigrate

I need to use [db-migrate](https://github.com/db-migrate/node-db-migrate) to add an index to a Postgres database with `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY`. However, db-migrate wraps all migrations in a transaction by default, and trying to create a concurrent index inside a transaction results in this error code:

`CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY cannot run inside a transaction block`

I can't find any way to disable transactions as part of the db-migrate options, either CLI options or (preferably) as a configuration directive on the migration itself. Any idea if this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that this can be solved on the command line by using `--non-transactional`. Reading the source, I can see that this sets an internal flag called `notransactions`, but it's not clear to me whether this can be set as part of the migration configuration or must be passed on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting the errors even when running with `--non-transactional` flag.

The solution for me was to run with `--non-transactional` AND have each `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` statement in its own separate migration file. It turns out you can't have more than one of it in the same file (same transaction block).